# Getting links to work the same on development and production

Tags: permalinks, site-url

I am working on a website where I am specifying links to pages within my site in other pages.

I am using the same permalink post name structure i.e. http://example.com/sample-post on both development and production and I am using /index.php/sample-post/ to link to a specific blog. This works on production but not on development.

My development machine's wordpress install is under a directory called wordpress and is running off a URL http://127.0.1.1:8080/wordpress/

On development for some reason when I specify /index.php/sample-post the wordpress part of the site url is absent. This only seems to happen with posts and not pages.

As far as I know /index.php/ refers to the site url which should be http://127.0.1.1:8080/wordpress/ unless I am mistaken. Moreover I would like to know if there is any alternative way to specify absolute URLs in wordpress and get around this problem.

Thanks in advance.
nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work this out. I have posted the step on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086115/wordpress-is-cut-off-when-linking-to-pages-using-index-php-page-name).

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

I suppose that you have a backend interface that use custom fields to do this.

Don't use permalinks in this fields, instead save the post_id of the page that you want to link in the custom field and use `get_permalink()` in your code

Example:
Custom field name: `link_to_page`

In your code, use, for example

```
echo get_permalink(get_post_meta($post->post_id,'link_to_page',true))
```

In the backend, you can use custom meta boxes. See [this article](http://www.farinspace.com/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-meta-box/) for reference on how to implemente custom meta boxes

Comment: I am not using the link to the page in my code I am using it in my content. Hence, I cannot execute PHP code like `echo get_permalink();` as you have suggested. I do not intend to use a plugin to do this either as the method detailed in the [codex to linking pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Linking_Posts_Pages_and_Categories) should work the same on both development and production.

Comment: Ok, use index.php/sample-post instead of /index.php in your code